# GCS metrices in google monitoring dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-storage

While coming to storage metrices, there are just options provided 'object count', 'Total Bytes' , 'Total byte seconds' . What if I need few more metrices like object whose **retention period** are about to over, **maximum size of an object in the bucket** etc. How can I achieve such metrices using monitoring dashboard?

Comment: I've checked the GCP environment but unfortunately their was no metrices for retention period and maximum size of an object in the bucket, I advice you to create a feature request for another metrices dashboard on Cloud Storage.

Comment: In meanwhile is there any way around to fetch such metrices, (ex: max size of an object in the bucket) with something like log based or with big query?

Comment: you can check [Metric Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer#find-me) from the documentation you can choose a specific metrics to create a chart for a specific metric categories using configuration (Console) or fetching of data using the query editor (MQL or PROMQL) then save to a [custom dashboard.](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/dashboards)

Answer (score 0):

Tried to replicate on my GCP environment but unfortunately their was no metrices for retention period and maximum size of an object in the bucket, I recommend you to create a feature request for another metrices dashboard for Cloud Storage. Regarding to your other inquiry you can check [Metric Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer#find-me) from the documentation you can choose a specific metrics to create a chart for a specific metric categories using configuration (Console) or fetching of data using the query editor (MQL or PROMQL) then save to a [custom dashboard.](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/dashboards)